# Map JSON values in Elixir

Tags: elixir, jsonparser, elixir-poison

I have parsed the following JSON using Posion.decode!

```
json = %{"color-Black|size:10" => 
    %{"attributes" => %{"color" => "Black","size" => "11"},    
      "isAvailable" => true,      
    "pricing" => %{"standard" => "$415.00", "sale" => 415}}, 
 "color|size-EU:9.5" => 
    %{"attributes" => %{"color" => "Black","size" => "11"},    
      "isAvailable" => true,      
    "pricing" => %{"standard" => "$415.00", "sale" => 415}}}
```

I want to map this and I'm unable to get JSON elements as the text in the node element changes.
So far I've tried.

```
Enum.map(json , fn(item) ->
%{
  color: item.attributes["color"],                 
  size: item.attributes["size"],
  price: item.pricing["standard"] * 100,
  isAvailable: item.isAvailable
 }
end)
```

But this code gives some error related to accessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While mapping the map, the iterated key-value pairs come to the mapper as tuples `{key, value}`:

```rb
Enum.map(json, fn {_, %{"attributes" => attributes,
                        "isAvailable" => isAvailable,
                        "pricing" => pricing}} ->
  %{
    color: attributes["color"],
    size: attributes["size"],
    price: pricing["standard"],
    isAvailable: isAvailable
   }
end)

#⇒ [
#    %{color: "Black", isAvailable: true, price: "$415.00", size: "11"},
#    %{color: "Black", isAvailable: true, price: "$415.00", size: "11"}
# ]
```

Here we use an inplace pattern matching for values in mapper to simplify the code of matcher itself and make it less error-prone in a case of bad input.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

1. You have a map so `Enum.map` will give you a tuple of key and value. You just want the value here, so do:

   ```
   fn {_, item} ->
   ```
2. The keys in your map are strings. The dot syntax only works for atom keys. You need to do:

   ```
   item["attributes"]
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   item.attributes
   ```

   and similar for other keys.
3. The price you have is a string. You'll need to convert it to a Float before you can multiply it. You can do it like this using `String.trim_leading` and `String.to_float`:

   ```
   iex(1)> "$123.45" |> String.trim_leading("$") |> String.to_float
   123.45
   ```

---

```
Enum.map(json, fn {_, item} ->
  %{
    color: item["attributes"]["color"],
    size: item["attributes"]["size"],
    price: item["pricing"]["standard"] |> String.trim_leading("$") |> String.to_float |> Kernel.*(100),
    isAvailable: item["isAvailable"]
  }
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{color: "Black", isAvailable: true, price: 4.15e4, size: "11"},
 %{color: "Black", isAvailable: true, price: 4.15e4, size: "11"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting access errors because you can only use the `thing.property` syntax if `property` is an atom and in your json map, the keys are strings.

One thing that will make this much easier is that `Poison.decode` can take a second argument of `keys: :atoms` to return a map with atom keys. Working with what you have here, this will solve the problem:

```
json_atoms = Poison.encode!(json) |> Poison.decode!(keys: :atoms)
convert_price = fn x -> 
  String.trim_leading(x, "$")
  |> String.to_float
  |> &(&1 * 100)
  |> trunc
end

Enum.map(json_atoms, fn {_k,v} -> %{
  color: v.attributes.color,
  size: v.attributes.size,
  price: convert_price.(v.pricing.standard),
  isAvailable: v.isAvailable
} end)
```

Comment: Word of warning: atoms don't get garbage collected, so if you parse a lot of JSON with different keys, this could become a problem. https://github.com/devinus/poison#parser

Comment: There is an atom limit and they're not garbage collected (yet), but in this case, the JSON has a consistent shape. So the only atoms created would be :size, :color, :price and :is_available. I've never seen an app get anywhere near the limit FWIW.